# prepared statement node sqlite3 and Like keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

Im trying to create a function that lets me search and order a list using Node and SQLite3. Im not quite sure what I am doing wrong, but when I include the sort parameter the code stops working and I get "Error: SQLITE_ERROR: Near "?": syntax error".

This is the code.

```
exports.search = function(name, sort, sortAscDesc, cb) {

var sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Crimestat";

if (name != undefined) {
    name = "%" + name + "%";
    sqlQuery += " WHERE municipacility LIKE ?";
}

if (sort != undefined) {
    if (sortAscDesc != undefined) {
        sqlQuery += " ORDER BY ? ?";
    } else {
        sqlQuery += " ORDER BY ASC";
    }
}

console.log("sql query " + sqlQuery)

db.all(sqlQuery, name, sort, sortAscDesc, function(err, row) {
    if (row == undefined) {
        console.log("error " + err)
        cb(false);
    } else {
        cb(row);
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `sqlQuery += " ORDER BY ASC";` what are you trying to order here (just wondering). I'm not sure if you can orderby with the ? ?  syntax have you found this in the documentation? can't you add the columns instead of the ?

Comment: im trying to put ASC or DESC using the sortAscDesc parameter that I take in to the function

Comment: Oh i see what you mean now. I forgot the ? in the "ORDER BY ASC", thats supposed to be "ORDER BY ? ASC"

Comment: Yes and are you sure this orderby works with the ? operator?

Comment: just to be sure try replace your `? ?` with the actual column names!?

Comment: I haven no idea if ? works with order by operator, im testing a few things now, but I could atleast change "? ?" to "?"

Comment: I tryed it myself, I don't think you can do `ORDER BY ? ?`, and your args array `["column1", "column2"]`. You need to write `ORDER BY column1 column2 ASC`